# mod_rewrite adding full directory

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a .htaccess file to control my Apache server. After turning RewriteEngine On, I have a rewrite rule which works properly:

```
RewriteRule ^display\.php/([a-zA-Z0-9-z\-]+)$ "https://pastelink.net/display?q=$1" [R=301,L]
```

On the next line I am trying to add another rule in, to redirect sitemap.xml to sitemap.php.

I have tried both:

```
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ "https://pastelink.net/sitemap.php" [R=301, L]
```

and

```
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml sitemap.php [R=301, L]
```

As well as other combinations including or omitting ^ $ and the flags. The result each time is a rewrite to this:

```
https://pastelink.net/home/pastelin/public_html/sitemap.php
```

when my intention is this:

```
https://pastelink.net/sitemap.php
```

Why are these extra directories added into the URL? I can't see why it would behave differently to the first rewrite rule. I can post the entire .htaccess file if that helps, though the L flag should make the code that follows irrelevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `http://` for silent rewrite rules. Keep your root .htaccess as this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^display\.php/([\w-]+)/?$ https://pastelink.net/display?q=$1 [R=301,L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^sitemap\.xml$ sitemap.php [NC,L]
```

You should clear browser cache before testing these changes.